# How do I get the shadow copy path of ASP.NET files if my ASP.NET project targets .NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I created an ASP.NET Web Forms project using Visual Studio 2013 Express and just compiled the project without making any changes.

I'd like to see the shadow copy of the assemblies of this project.

I am looking at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` but do not see any of the files I expect.

I even tried printing this on the page to see where the shadow copy path is:

```
Response.Write("Shadow Copying Enabled: ");
Response.Write(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyFiles);
Response.Write("<br />");
Response.Write("Shadow Copy Path: ");
Response.Write(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyDirectories);
```

But it prints out the path of the bin directory and the shadow copying is enabled.

Basically, I am after seeing that class library that has the class that ASP.NET generates using CodeDom -- the class that derives from the class whose name we see in the code behind file.

What is the location of the shadow copy files if the project targets the .NET 4.5 version of the framework?

Comment: Shadow copying is done by the server, upon loading your application. Did you try running it?

Comment: Yes, after running it I tried. I've updated the question.

Comment: Did you try to `Optionally set a custom location for shadow copied files by using the CACHEPATH property and the APPLICATIONNAME property.` as stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx)